# can i store the OAuthSerice object in jdo

Tags: google-app-engine

Hi please check my code i got 
2012-10-25 18:22:17.803

com.cloudcodes.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Exception message : org.scribe.oauth.OAuth10aServiceImpl

W 2012-10-25 18:22:17.804

com.cloudcodes.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Error in class LinkedInCallBackUrl

W 2012-10-25 18:22:17.804

com.cloudcodes.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
 java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1197)

W 2012-10-25 18:22:17.804

com.cloudcodes.ErrorHandler errorHandler:
 java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:363)

this error
        OAuthService  service = new ServiceBuilder()
              .provider(LinkedInApi.class)
              .apiKey("jfih0cg6ihc1")
               .apiSecret("nFxDxjA4T6jgq5JD").scope("r_network rw_nus")
                 .callback("http://mygbuddy.appspot.com/DisplayConnections.jsp")
                 .build();
        Token requestToken=service.getRequestToken();
        HttpSession session=req.getSession();

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    oos.writeObject(service);
    byte[] oauthobject = bos.toByteArray();
    String oauth=new String(oauthobject);
    String tokenvalue=requestToken.getToken();
    String tokenSecert=requestToken.getSecret();
```

and i am store those details in jdo by using my bean class

Comment: You can't because it's not serializable.

Comment: thanks for the replay but now i want to send the OAuth object from servlet to jsp how can do?in my project i got linkedin oauth by using scribe i need this oauth object in jsp.please help me